# SQL query suggestions please

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to write a SQL query to calculate prices for licenses.
Please check the schema below:

Table: **Prices**

```
| ID (bigint) | USERS(Bigint) |  TYPE (varchar) | PRICE (BIGINT)
------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1          |        1      |      other      |       20     |
|  2          |        15     |      local      |       13.96  |
```

Table: **Licenses**

```
| ID (bigint) | USERID (Bigint) |STATUS(VARCHAR) |  USERS(bigint) | DEVICES(BIGINT) | TYPE(VARCHAR) | REQUEST_TYPE (VARCHAR) | 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1          |    13           |      10        |       10        |     local     |           add          | 
|  2          |    13           |      15        |       20        |     other     |           extend       |
```

My objective:

Given a userid and type, i want to calculate total prices of all the licenses of basing on following critirea:

For given userid and type:

1) Get all licenses which have request_type as either new (or) extend

2) For each such license, match the number of users (USERS column) with USERS column from 'prices' table and do calculation as devices*(associated price from prices table)

3) Using this calculate sum of all such prices and return a total price.

I'm trying to do this by using the following query but i'm not successful yet:

```
SELECT SUM(PRICE) FROM prices
LEFT OUTER JOIN licenses
ON ( 
  prices.users=licenses.users
  AND prices.type=licenses.type
)
WHERE licenses.userid=13
AND licenses.status='approved'
AND licenses.request_type IN ('add','extend')
```

Please check SQL Fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/05f5cf

Pleas help.

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 0):

From your comments and updates, I think you want (not sure if it's necessary to compare users in license and users in price, but it seems youd want this)

```
select coalesce(sum( p.users * p.price), 0)
FROM licenses l
inner join prices p
  on  p.type = l.type
  --and p.users = l.users
where l.status = 'approved'
and l.request_type in ('add', 'extend')
and l.userid = 13
```

**Edit**

In fact, do you need to check that type AND users are identical, or just users ?

If you need only check on users, then

```
inner join prices p
  on  p.users = l.users
```

If you need only check on type

```
inner join prices p 
  on p.type = l.type
```

If you need both, you will get 0 with your sample datas.

See [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cd2731/17) with 3 versions.

Comment: Thank you. But there is a price in this query i want to get price*no of devices in the licenses but this return only price

Comment: @user2818666 and what's no of devices in your table ?

Comment: @Althaus Thank you. Looks like the third approach is what i need. I have one question, is it possible to find a situation where: at licences table have a type="other" and users=15 
  but at prices table haven't have type="other" and users=15,    i mean like generating a error somehow in such cases?

Comment: @user2818666 Hmmmm you would do that in the same query ? In another query that would be easy, but I don't know what you need.

Answer (score 0):

the result will be null, because query cannot found the condition of LEFT OUTER JOIN

there is the query

```
SELECT SUM(PRICE) FROM prices
LEFT OUTER JOIN licenses
ON ( 
  prices.users=licenses.users
  AND prices.type=licenses.type //cannot found condition on table
)
WHERE licenses.userid=13 
AND licenses.status='approved'
AND licenses.request_type IN ('add','extend')
```

in this is the data inside table

table licences

```
(1, 'approved', 10, 10, 'local', 'add', 13),
(2, 'approved', 15, 20, 'other', 'extend', 13);
```

and table prices

```
(1, 1, 'other', 20),
(2, 15, 'local', 13.96);
```

and your condition is

```
  prices.users=licenses.users
  AND prices.type=licenses.type //cannot found condition on table
 that mean if from your table is

  at licences table have a type="other" and users=15 
  but at prices table haven't have type="other" and users=15
```

so the result will be null

because when i change the first row of table prices 
    (1, 1, 'other', 20)
    becomes     (1, 15, 'other', 20),

that will be have a result = 20

you need change your first line of query

```
SELECT SUM(PRICE) FROM prices

be

SELECT IFNULL(SUM(PRICE),0) FROM prices
```

this will change the result if haven't found the row to 0 not null